Reusing static lifetime thread in a scoped setting to avoid spawn overhead
I am writing a rust component that does multi-threaded operations for performance. To achieve this, I am using scoped threads and channels that pass references with lifetime annotations. My approach works, but has poor performance due to many threads being spawned.
I am looking for a solution that will allow one thread to be re-used without violating lifetimes.
My current solution binds the lifetime of a crossbeam scope to crossbeam channels to allow safely passing references between threads. Here is a simple example:
use crossbeam::thread;
use crossbeam::thread::Scope;
use crossbeam_channel::unbounded;
use crossbeam_channel::Receiver;
use crossbeam_channel::Sender;

fn slice_processor_worker<'a>(rx: Receiver<&'a mut [u8]>, tx: Sender<&'a mut [u8]>) {
    // Process the first slice.
    let data = rx.recv().unwrap();
    println!("received {:?} inside worker", data);
    data[0] = 15;
    let _ = tx.send(data);

    // Process the second slice.
    let data = rx.recv().unwrap();
    println!("received {:?} inside worker", data);
    let _ = tx.send(data);
}

fn slice_processor<'scope>(
    scope: &Scope<'scope>,
) -> (Sender<&'scope mut [u8]>, Receiver<&'scope mut [u8]>) {
    let (main_tx, processor_rx) = unbounded();
    let (processor_tx, main_rx) = unbounded();

    scope.spawn(|_| slice_processor_worker(processor_rx, processor_tx));

    (main_tx, main_rx)
}

fn main() {
    let mut data = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    thread::scope(|scope| {
        let (tx, rx) = slice_processor(scope);
        let (first_half, second_half) = data.split_at_mut(5);

        scope.spawn(move |_| {
            let _ = tx.send(first_half);
            println!("received {:?} in main", rx.recv().unwrap());
            let _ = tx.send(second_half);
            println!("received {:?} in main", rx.recv().unwrap());
        });
    })
    .unwrap();
}

This code works, but is causing performance issues. My use case requires performing this multithreaded operation many times across many code paths during execution, and I'm running into overhead from spawning threads.
Ideally, I would create one thread with static lifetime and bind the scoped channels to that thread. That way I only need to pay the thread spawning overhead once. I have been unable to find a solution that achieves this. Maybe someone who knows more about lifetimes and concurrency in rust can find a solution?

Easiest solution: just use rayon.

I'm using channels and scoped threads to achieve operation pipelining. I don't see how to achieve similar functionality with rayon. Rayon appears to process all data in one shot.

@s690832 rayon does provide more than parallel iterators.

As described, the answer to this is just par_chunks_mut. If that doesn't work for you, you'll need to ask a question that better represents your situation.

You can use a threadpool with scoped threads support.

I think the best solution here is to move ownership of the operating data to the thread rather than keeping it in the outer scope. The data can be placed into an Arc before moving to the threads. This effectively gives the data a 'static lifetime (really the type has a 'static lifetime) so can be moved/sent between threads.
If you are streaming data rather than the single dataset you have in your example then you should use a thread pool system (like async tokio or a blocking thread pool library) in conjunction with multiple buffers. If you are relay performance constrained (to the point where an allocation per buffer is too much, this is a crazy requirement) you can rotate the buffers back into a buffer pool as well.
You're example doesn't really match your requirements description so please add more about the problem you're trying to solve if you can so I can post a more accurate and detailed answer.
